# hit test point conditional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to use hitTestPoint syntax to start a timer when all of my chosen objects are in the correct place. They all snap to their correct location when they are dragged over and released in proximity to it. Unfortunately my timer will not start. I cannot figure out why it will not start. My flash professor cannot figure it out either. I will check back on this question soon, and hopefully I have given you guys all you need to make it happen.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,completion);
function completion(event:Event):void
{

    if (EYEOVERLEFT_MC.hitTestPoint(EYELEFT_MC.x,EYELEFT_MC.y) && 
        EYEOVERRIGHT_MC.hitTestPoint(EYERIGHT_MC.x,EYERIGHT_MC.y) && 
        NOSEOVER_MC.hitTestPoint(NOSEUNDER_MC.x,NOSEUNDER_MC.y) &&
        LOCKOVER_MC.hitTestPoint(LOCKUNDER_MC.x,LOCKUNDER_MC.y) &&
        ROSEOVER_MC.hitTestPoint(ROSEUNDER_MC.x,ROSEUNDER_MC.y) &&
        CHAINOVER_MC.hitTestPoint(CHAINUNDER_MC.x,CHAINUNDER_MC.y) &&
        LEAFOVER_MC.hitTestPoint(LEAFUNDER_MC.x,LEAFUNDER_MC.y)){

        var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,2);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);
            timer.start();
            trace("Timer Start");
        }

        function timerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            trace("Timer Finished");
        }

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,completion);
        nextFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: What prevents your code from creating timers endlessly? Your `completion` function is called for every frame. If the condition is met once, it'll be met on every subsequent frame and the timer will be created.

Comment: Your code sample is also a mess. You should clean it up to make sure braces match up.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is simple - you just haven't made the correct checks in the `if` statement - not all of them are true.

So you need to check each of the (with multiple if statements) and see where's the problem. Some of the conditions are not ok and this may be the result of your other logic (which moves those things around).

We cannot help you with them, so keep digging this if-horror..

p.s.
It's nice to try keeping your code well formatted and well designed. Don't use upper case!

**EDIT**: why you move to nextFrame? I'm not sure this is okay for that timer :)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Popov, I apologize to all for my crude coding. Are you suggesting I splice an "if" function in between all of my conditionals? Is this troubleshooting or part of the necessary code.

Comment: It's a must for troubleshooting and debugging, but it's generally nice to not have such long if statements as it 's hard to read, hard to maintain and as you can see - hard to debug :) It would be nice if you make a helper function so you can do just: `if (hits(eyeOverLeft, eyeLeft)) {` - looks easier, right?